# Как обозначить активный элемент в меню с использованием Bootstrap u thymeleaf?

Tags: html, bootstrap4, thymeleaf, navigationbar

Есть панель навигации, в которой классом active должен маркироваться активный элемент, но возник вопрос, как с использованием thymeleaf либо в javascript получить адрес текущей страницы, к примеру /login, /home, /map для того чтобы дальше использовать для добавления класса "active" к элементу : th:classappend="${module == 'login' ? 'active' : ''}, ведь элемент module приходится в ручную добавлять в каждом контроллере в post и get запросах, что не очень изящно. Вот собственно navbar со всеми элементами:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-ligth bg-fadded">
        <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/}">
            <img class="home-logo" alt="UTL-2" th:src="@{/static/img/site-logo.png}"/></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul id="myDIV" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${module == 'login' ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/login}">Вход
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${module == 'plan' ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/plan}">График <br/>отгрузки</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${module == 'orders' ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/orders}">Заявки</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${module == 'stations' ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/stations}">Справочник <br/>станций</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/partner}">Справочник <br/>контрагентов</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/map}">Карта</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/info}">Информация</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light" th:href="@{/admin}">Панель <br/>администратора</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <div id="logged-in-info">
                <span sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">Hello, <b sec:authentication="name">(Anonimous)</b></span>
                <!--<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUsername()}"></span>-->

                <form sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" method="post" th:action="@{/logout}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="Logout"/>
                </form>
                <form sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" method="post" th:action="@{/login}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


    </nav>
```

Использовал для всего этого скрипт он выполняется, но каждый пункт меню ведет на новую страницу и класс "active" при обновлении пропадает:

```html
    <script>
        // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
        var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
        for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                if (current.length > 0) {
                    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                this.className += " active";
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил совершенно бешенный javascript который по адресу текущей активной страницы добавляет "active" класс к элементу с сылкой на текущую страницу, но это как колесо изобретать, неужели нету встроенного механизма в bootstrap или thymeleaf как решить эту проблему существующими методами. Собственно код следующий:

```html
<script>
        var currentPage = window.location.pathname;
        //Получаем список элементов
        var items = document.getElementById("myDIV").getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
        var activeClass = "active";
        //записываем паттерн, в котором убираем "/"
        var patt = new RegExp(currentPage.split("/")[1],"i");

        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            var navItem = items[i];
            //в дочернем элементе получаем ссылку на последний элемент в иерархии адреса
            var linkArray = navItem.children[0].href.split("/");
            var linkHTML = linkArray[linkArray.length - 1];
            if(patt.test(linkHTML)){
            //добавляем класс к элементу
                navItem.classList.add("active");
            }
        }
    </script>
```